# Determining the largest sum of contiguous integers in a list

Tags: java, stream

I'm curious how I can improve the readability of this short program I wrote. Mainly, if and how there is a way to remove the `for` loops and maybe refactor the `getTruncatedSubListsOf` methods to one method since they are pretty similar. I tried using comments only when clarification was necessary.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.*;

import static java.util.Arrays.asList;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;


/**
 *  A program to determine the largest sum of contiguous integers in a list.
 *  The first argument is a path to a filename containing a comma-separated list of integers, one per line.
 *  The largest sum is printed to stdout. In other words, of all the possible contiguous subarrays for a given array,
 *  the one with the largest sum is found and printed.
 */
public class SumOfIntegers {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(args[0])).lines()
                                                    .map(SumOfIntegers::turnToIntegerList)
                                                    .map(SumOfIntegers::getAllContiguousSubarrays)
                                                    .map(SumOfIntegers::getSumsOfSubarrays)
                                                    .mapToInt(Collections::max)
                                                    .forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    private static List<Integer> turnToIntegerList(String line) {

        return asList(line.split(",")).stream()
                                      .map(Integer::valueOf)
                                      .collect(toList());
    }

    /**
     * Returns all possible contiguous subarrays for a given List. This method calls getEndTruncatedSubListsOf each
     * different frontTruncatedSubList, yielding all possible front and end truncated lists - which are all subarrays.
     * @param integerList A List containing Integer values.
     * @return A List of all subarrays as Lists.
     */
    private static List<List<Integer>> getAllContiguousSubarrays(List<Integer> integerList) {
        List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();

        for (List<Integer> frontTruncatedSubList : getFrontTruncatedSubListsOf(integerList)) {
            result.addAll(getEndTruncatedSubListsOf(frontTruncatedSubList));
        }

        return result;
    }

    private static List<List<Integer>> getFrontTruncatedSubListsOf(List<Integer> list) {
        List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            result.add(list.subList(i, list.size()));
        }

        return result;
    }

    private static List<List<Integer>> getEndTruncatedSubListsOf(List<Integer> list) {
        List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            result.add(list.subList(0, list.size() - i));
        }

        return result;
    }

    private static List<Integer> getSumsOfSubarrays(List<List<Integer>> subarrays) {
        return subarrays.stream()
                .map(subsubarray -> subsubarray.stream()
                                                .mapToInt(integer -> integer)
                                                .sum())
                .collect(toList());
    }



}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functions you have like:

> ```
> private static List<List<Integer>> getEndTruncatedSubListsOf(List<Integer> list)   {
>     List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
>
>     for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
>         result.add(list.subList(0, list.size() - i));
>     }
>
>     return result;
> }
> ```

Can be expressed in streams as:

```
private static List<List<Integer>> getEndTruncatedSubListsOf(List<Integer> list) {
    return IntStream.range(0, list.size())
                    .mapToObj(i -> list.subList(0, list.size() - i))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Streaming over the indicies of a List is the generalized mechanism for indexing the contents of a list inside a stream.

It is debatable whether the streaming option is easier to read - if you are familiar with streams, it's not too bad, but in your case, your for-loop version is neat, readable, and I would not hesitate to "approve" it in a review.

There's one factoring that could be useful though, which is to express the truncation operation as a function, and pass the function in to a more abstract truncate function. Consider:

```
private static List<List<Integer>> getEndTruncatedSubListsOf(List<Integer> list) {
    return getSubListsOf(list, i -> list.subList(0, list.size() - i));
}

private static List<List<Integer>> getFrontTruncatedSubListsOf(List<Integer> list) {
    return getSubListsOf(list, i -> list.subList(i, list.size()));
}

private static List<List<Integer>> getSubListsOf(List<Integer> list,
        IntFunction<List<Integer>> truncfn) {
    return IntStream.range(0, list.size())
                    .mapToObj(i -> truncfn.apply(i))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

You can see this running [in ideone](https://ideone.com/oy4Tn8)

Also, note that you can completely generify the methods too:

```
private static <T> List<List<T>> getEndTruncatedSubListsOf(List<T> list) {
    return getSubListsOf(list, i -> list.subList(0, list.size() - i));
}

private static <T> List<List<T>> getFrontTruncatedSubListsOf(List<T> list) {
    return getSubListsOf(list, i -> list.subList(i, list.size()));
}

private static <T> List<List<T>> getSubListsOf(List<T> list,
        IntFunction<List<T>> truncfn) {
    return IntStream.range(0, list.size())
                    .mapToObj(i -> truncfn.apply(i))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Again, [in ideone](https://ideone.com/9tHBHL)

Comment: Thanks! Wouldn't it be useless to make the Lists use generics if the arguments will be used on arithmetic operators later? Like, applying `getFrontTruncatedSubListsOf`on generic Objects will throw an Exception.

Answer (score 3):

#### Unit testing

As it currently stands, testing your class means having to feed it a filesystem-based input (even if it's using something in-memory like [Jimfs](https://github.com/google/jimfs)). You should consider implementing your application logic such that the input is the form of `Stream<String>`, so that the source of that stream is independent of the processing here.

#### `String` splitting as `Stream<String>`

```
Array.asList(string.split(",")).stream()
```

This can be better represented using [`Pattern.splitAsStream(CharSequence)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#splitAsStream-java.lang.CharSequence-)

```
// consider making Pattern.compile(",") a static Pattern field too
Pattern.compile(",").splitAsStream(string)
```